# Querying large Mongodb collection using pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I want to query my mongodb collection which has more than 5k records, each record has key-value pair like

```
{
 "A" : "unique-value1",
 "B" : "service1",
 "C" : 1.2321,
 ...
},
...
```

here `A` will always have `unique` value, `B` has value like `service1, service2, ....service8` and C is some float value.

what I want is to get a record like this with key-value pair.

```
{
 "A" : "unique-value1",
 "B" : "service1",
 "C" : 1.2321
}

{
  "A" : "unique-value2",
  "B" : "service2",
  "C" : 0.2321
}
{
  "A" : "unique-value3",
  "B" : "service1",
  "C" : 3.2321
}
```

**I am not sure how to do this, earlier I used MapReduce but that time I was needed to generate records with `A` and `C` key value paire only but now since i also need `B` i do not know what should i do.**

this is what i was doing

```
map_reduce = Code("""
        function () {
            emit(this.A, parseFloat(this.C));
        }
        """)
result = my_collection.map_reduce(map_reduce, reduce, out='temp_collection')

for doc in result.find({}):
    out = dict()
    out[doc['_id']] = doc['_id']
    out['cost'] = doc['value']
    out_handle.update_one(
        {'A': doc['_id']},
        {'$set': out},
        upsert=True
        )
```

Comment: Please tell what you have tried so far. What is the difficulty?

Comment: hi @prasad i have updated code, earlier i was saving only two fields, so i used map reduce, but now i need `{
 "A" : "unique-value1",
 "B" : "service1",
 "C" : 1.2321
}
` this

Comment: Looks like you just want to _project_ few fields ( "A", "B" and "C") from the source documents: [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood what you need , it looks like you are making this harder than it need be. Just project the keys you want using the second parameter of the find method.

```
for record in db.testcollection.find({}, { 'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}):
    db.existingornewcollection.replace_one({'_id': record['_id']}, record, upsert=True)
```

Full example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps
db = MongoClient()['testdatabase']

db.testcollection.insert_one({
    "A": "unique-value1",
    "B": "service1",
    "C": 1.2321,
    "D": "D",
    "E": "E",
    "F": "F",
})

for record in db.testcollection.find({}, { 'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}):
    db.existingornewcollection.replace_one({'_id': record['_id']}, record, upsert=True)

print(dumps(db.existingornewcollection.find_one({}, {'_id': 0}), indent=4))
```

gives:

```
{
    "A": "unique-value1",
    "B": "service1",
    "C": 1.2321
}
```